# How to get object name data list with where condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want get spesific data form my name object **jumlahproduksi** data but i got a problem not working with i tried this code.
I use grep function because need where condition base city(lokasi)

```
var e = 0;    
while (e < kota.length) {
    var filtered = $.grep(data, function (el) {
        return el.lokasi == kota[e];
    });
    
    console.log(filtered);
 e = e+1;
}
```

I have data like this:
[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B0u6.png)
I want the data model like this: Show **jumlahproduksi**
[model data i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7krA.png)

So Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: You aren't applying a "filter" to your data, you're applying a **projection** (it's just that the projection is selecting a single property value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pro-itp: Don't use jQuery's `grep` to search through JSON because you cannot meaningfully extract data from JSON in all circumstances using a Regular Expression [because JSON is not a Regular Language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language).

Moving on, just use JSON the way it's intended to be consumed: as native JS objects. You can use `Array.map` to apply a **projection** to an input array, like so:

```
var jsonInput = `[
    { "tahun": "2015", "lokasi": "Kab. Benhulu Seltan", "jumlahproduksi": "0" },
    { "tahun": "2016", "lokasi": "Kab. Benhulu Seltan", "jumlahproduksi": "0" },
    { "tahun": "2017", "lokasi": "Kab. Benhulu Seltan", "jumlahproduksi": "9795" }
]`;
var root = JSON.parse( jsonInput );
var values = root.map( e => e.jumlahproduksi );

console.log( values ); // [ "0", "0", "9795" ]
```

Here's a JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/60ncb3g1/

Comment: could you help with jsfidlle, your example code get error unexpected token json parse anonymous

Comment: @Nipurbalistore I've amended my answer with a JSFiddle example.

Comment: bro I write code inside of JQuery the data JSON from ajax, so i got error unexpected token json parse  anonymous, you have another idea?

Comment: @Nipurbalistore Please post a sample of the raw response (as text) in your question. Does the JSON you're receiving have double-quotes around the object key names or are they unquoted?

Comment: my data :
[{ tahun: "2017", lokasi: "Kab. Benhulu Seltan", jumlahproduksi: "9795" }]

your example data:
[{ "tahun": "2017", "lokasi": "Kab. Benhulu Seltan", "jumlahproduksi": "9795" }]

problem : json parse unexpected token.
That is the problem bro, how?  sorry wasting your time

Comment: bro thank you so much in that case i don't need a json parse, just map, its working now. thank you very much